# Alfresco: get first name and lastname from person

Tags: alfresco-share

I need help to get the name and surname from personInfo, I have username from user.

My code is:

```
    //get person from username
    NodeRef person = personService.getPerson(username);

    //error
    PersonInfo personInfo = personService.getPerson(person);

    String firstName = personInfo.getFirstName();
    String lastName = personInfo.getLastName();
```

error is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.alfresco.service.cmr.security.PersonService.getPerson(Lorg/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/NodeRef;)Lorg/alfresco/service/cmr/security/PersonService$PersonInfo;
```

method is:

[image]

Where's my mistake?

Alfresco is version 4.2.c, alfresco-maven-sdk is 1.1.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't have right SDK for alfresco 4.2.c, that not containt above method. I found anatoher solution:

```
    NodeRef personRef = personService.getPerson(assignee);

    String firstName = nodeService.getProperty(personRef, ContentModel.PROP_FIRSTNAME).toString();
    String lastName = nodeService.getProperty(personRef, ContentModel.PROP_LASTNAME).toString();
```